# What is the radius of convergence of $\frac{\sinh(z)}z$ about $z=\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a question that asks to find the radius of convergence for $\frac{sinh(z)}z$ about $z=\pi$. I attempted to solve this as: $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sinh(z)}z = \frac{\cosh(z)}z - \frac{\sinh(z)}{z^2}$$
which isn't defined at $z=0$, therefore the radius of convergence would be: $$R=\lvert{0-pi}\lvert = \pi$$
is this correct?

Comment: The concept of *radius of convergence* applies to power  series representations of functions, not to the functions themselves.

Comment: It isn’t defined at $0,$ but the limit exists, as is true for $\sinh z/z.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\sinh(z)=\frac12\left(e^z-e^{-z}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

So what what is the nature of $\frac{\sinh z}{z}$ at $z=0?$

Comment: would it be an isolated singularity at z=0? Would that mean radius of convergence is pi even if my method is incorrect?

Comment: No. What happens when you divide the power series by $z.$ Does it look like there is really a singularity at $0$? @hpSauce_